# Regex - How to detect if block of text only has URLs in it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a way to detect if a block of text only has URLs in it. Another way to say it would be to see if a block of text doesn't have any text besides what is in a URL.

We're getting a lot of spam but one tell tale of a spammer is they often only post links and no other text.  So  they'll post

http://link1.xyz
http://link2.syx

and nothing else. Looking for a regex expression that could detect this. Using php as well.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: There are plenty of regular expressions for URLs available online if you search for them. What you could do is use `preg_replace()` to replace any URL with nothing, then `trim()` the result and check for `strlen($trimmedResult) === 0`. If you have trouble with any of that, please update your question with your attempts

Comment: What I had tried mainly consisted of searching the internet because I knew everything I was conceptualizing wouldn't work. @phil suggestion is what we'll go with. I'll post our results.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this RegEx with big success:

```
\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-\w+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-\w+&@#\/%=~_|]
```

Now all you have to do is check whether the match is equal to the Whole string.